# Livecode Strict isNumber() needed

Tags: regex, livecode

Livecode's isNumber returns true when certain text strings are used. isNumber("one") returns true. I need a "strict" isNumber function where any strings would return false. Needs to handle +/-, integers, reals, e notation preferably. I'm looking for a PCRE regex  for matchText(pValue, regexHere)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I've tried the solutions that are pointed to in the duplicate questions pointed out and these DO NOT WORK in Livecode Script. Please before marking as a duplicate, open up Livecode and try the 5 solutions provided (none of which are livecode examples).

Comment: FWIW I've voted to reopen - it does sound like [LiveCode supports the standard PCRE library](http://lists.runrev.com/pipermail/use-livecode/2013-January/181460.html), so the examples in those answers _should_ work.  Could you edit your question to include further examples of which of those you have tried - perhaps it's an issue of string escaping etc?

Comment: My thinking must be off on how matchText works. Here's a list of pValues and results

    put matchText(pValue, "[+\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?")
    1    true
    1.2  true
    -12.87 true
    2e2  true
    hello false
    4hello true???
    this is 2 times  true???

It appears as along as the matching text appears somewhere in the string, we get true back. Darn. not what I was looking for.

Comment: try adding `^` at the start and `$` at the end - those are the "start of string" and "end of string" anchors in regex - ie it should ensure you match the _whole_ string, not just a portion of it

Comment: I have voted to re-open this question. As soon as it is re-opened, I'll post my answer, which is really, really simple. No regex involved.